# Understanding the characterization of extreme points, basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I believe this is just a small question, but I cannot seem to understand it convincingly. In Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty, $3$rd edition, Characterization of Extreme Points theorem says something like:

> Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $m$ and an $m$-vector $b$, a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an extreme point of $S:=\{x:Ax=b,x\geq0\}$ if and only if $\{1,2,...,n\}$ can be partitioned into two sets $B,N$, where $|B|=m$, such that $A_B$ (matrix obtained by columns of $A$ indexed by $B$ increasingly) is non-singular and $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_B \\ x_N \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A_B^{-1}b \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\geq0$.

---

I am confused with the second-to-last equal sign, which is $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_B \\ x_N \end{pmatrix}$. Then, I went to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_feasible_solution#Examples and found an example. After reading through it, I think there is a mistake in the above theorem, and for now I conclude that the above should be written as just

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_B \\ x_N \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A_B^{-1}b \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\geq0$$

instead of

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}x_B \\ x_N \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A_B^{-1}b \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\geq0$$.

I mean, the first $x$ must not exist in the first place, because it will mean that our $x$ in the Wiki example will be $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_2 \\ x_4\\x_1\\x_3\\x_5 \end{pmatrix}$, and I am convinced this is not the case. Is my reasoning correct? Any suggestion is appreciated!

EDIT: Forgot to put $|B|=m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there was an abuse of notation.

$x_B$ need not be the first $m$ entries.

There is a permutation corresponding to $B$ such that

$$P_Bx = \begin{bmatrix}x_B \\ x_N \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I see. A few more questions if I may: 1. Can I say that this is an example where notation abuse is not tolerated? I mean, sure we can permute rows by permutation matrices multiplication, but in this case if (left-to-right direction) $x$ is a given extreme point, then it is fixed, so I am thinking the above assumption/abuse is a mistake.

Comment: 2. So for right-to-left direction, to find an extreme point, we simply (although not so simple) find $n\choose m$ columns of $A$ that form an invertible matrix $A_B$, and put $A_B^{-1}b$ first and follow it by $n-m$ zeros, and that is our extreme point $x$. Is that correct?

Comment: To me notations are meant for communication, whether it can be forgiven is up to the readers.:) no humans are perfect.  You mean find $m$ columsn of $A$ that form an invertible matrix $A_B$ and remember to check that $A_B^{-1}b\ge 0$,  of course there are $\binom{n}{m}$ choices. There are methods like $2$-phase simplex to find an extreme point.

Comment: Ahaha yes. What I mean was that, if there is a truth in the above usage of notation abuse, could you explain it to me? Because if the only thing I see here is that it is written incorrectly, I might actually get the concept wrong, right? Usually I understand some abuses of notation, but if in this case notation abuse can be used, I would like to know why. Simply put, I cannot see the intention of the authors writing it that way. I apologize if asking this is a bit much.

Comment: To add more reason, say I have the 2-by-5 matrix (1 5 3 4 6; 0 1 3 5 6) just like in Wiki, where $B=\{2,4\}$. I take $x=(0, 2, 0, 1, 0)^t$, and somehow I know using other methods that $x$ is an extreme point of $S$ (which it is). So, according to the characterization theorem above, we must also have $x=(2, 1, 0, 0, 0)^t$, which clearly differs with $x=(0, 2, 0, 1, 0)^t$. Hence, either (i) authors know the common rule of writing matrix but for some reason (which what I want to know) they still use it, or (ii) authors made a mistake, which of course is not impossible.

Comment: If it is truly (ii) that is happening, then I know my understanding is correct and it is a mistake, which is not about demanding authors will always be correct. However, it is (i), then I know something is wrong with my understanding.

Comment: $(ii)$, $(0,2,0,1,0)^t$ is the BFSt.  Sometimes, in some text, you might see WLOG, we assume the BFS is of the form of $(x_B^T, x_N^T)^T$. The reason it is WLOG is due to we consider permutation and some authors have chosen simplicity and focuses on the main idea, with some risk of miscommunication of course.

Comment: Are you implying that if $x$ is an extreme point of $S:=\{x:Ax=b,x\geq 0\}$, then so is any permutation of $x$? My apologies again as this is my first time studying programming.

Comment: no, for convenience of proving and notation, sometimes we abuse some notations, your understanding that there is a mistake is correct.

Comment: I am actually still figuring out what you mean by "we consider permutation". In the proof of this theorem, for the left-to-right direction, there is an assumption where $x$ is assumed to be $(x_1,x_2,...,x_m,0,0,...,0),x_i>0$. I understand this since the proof works the same if we permute it, but this is different with my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112444/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-10understanding).

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Say I have an $x$, where only some $m$-entries are positive. We use the permutation matrix $P$ such that $Px$ has its first $m$-entries positive. Our equation becomes $Ax=b\Rightarrow (AP^t)(Px)=b$, and hence the new $AP^t$ has its columns already adjusted. Is it correct?